# How can I get the selected row in Kendo Grid using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have the following jQuery code which is works to get the first row value but not the selected row:

```
function setStandardName() {
        var grid = $("#BillingsGrid").data("kendoGrid");
        var dataItem = grid.dataItem("tbody tr:eq(0)");       
        dataItem.set("Name", "new value");
        console.log(dataItem.Name); 
    };
```

It finds the first row value, but I need to get selected row value

I tried this:

```
function setStandardName() {
        var grid = $("#BillingsGrid").data("kendoGrid");
        var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this).closest("tr"));       
        dataItem.set("Name", "new value");
        console.log(dataItem.Name); 
    };
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of null on this line `dataItem.set("Name", "new value");`

Answer (score 0):

try like this.

```
$('.clickedSomething').click(function() {
    var grid = $("#BillingsGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this).closest("tr"));       
    dataItem.set("Name", "new value");
    console.log(dataItem.Name); 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get a seleted row and its each cell value like this sample:

```
var gridDataArray = $('#Grid').data('kendoGrid')._data;          
var selectedslug = gridDataArray[grid.select().index()]['Slug'];
```

and you can loop in that array for all rows data with foreach statement